# Ejercicio más antiguo de "los no prescritos"

Tags: significado

¿A qué se refiere "los no prescritos" en "Ejercicio más antiguo de los no prescritos", que se encuentra en este [enlace](https://aticojuridico.com/tag/ejercicio-mas-antiguo-de-los-no-prescritos/). Si he hecho la pregunta en el foro equivocado, por favor avísenme y la eliminaré en cuanto pueda. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Algo no prescrito en derecho quiere decir algo que todavia tiene vigencia o que está en vigor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Etiqueta: "Ejercicio más antiguo de los no prescritos."**

---

**Etiqueta**: En este contexto, "etiqueta" como título que sirve para identificar o clasificar determinados temas, en este caso, dentro de los temas judiciales.

"**Ejercicio más antiguo de los no prescritos.**"

(Declaraciones Judiciales sobre) Ejercicios Fiscales o Años Fiscales más antiguos de los que aún no han caducado.

---

Estos casos, como muy bien ha expuesto Cocteau, se refieren al tema del **IRPF** (**I**mpuesto de la **R**enta de las **P**ersonas **F**isicas).

(*La Agencia Estatal de Administración Tributaria de España o Fisco es el* *organismo estatal encargado de gestionar y tramitar los impuestos tanto de los ciudadanos como de las empresas, adscrita al Ministerio de Economía y Hacienda.*)

*El **IRPF** es un impuesto que grava la renta que cualquier contribuyente ha obtenido durante un año.* Aquellos que tienen la obligación anual de presentar su declaración de la renta es lo que llamamos, declaración fiscal del "Ejercicio o Año Fiscal", siendo su objetivo organizar las cuentas al final del año y ser la base del pago de impuestos.

El significado de Ejercicio o Ejercicios en este contexto en donde "el Ministerio de Hacienda" esta presente  refiriéndose a "**ejercicio como año fiscal**". "**El ejercicio fiscal o año fiscal como impuesto, gravará la renta de cualquier contribuyente que haya obtenido durante un año**". Por tanto varios ejercicios corresponden a "varios años fiscales".

***El año fiscal es el período de vigencia en el que se devengan los impuestos y que generalmente coincide con el año natural, es decir, empieza el 1 de enero y finaliza el 31 de diciembre.***

Por otra parte la **prescripción en este caso hace referencia a los plazos temporales**, así para que no haya prescrito una cosa debe de estar dentro del plazo temporal marcado por la ley, una vez el plazo expire o vaya más allá del tiempo establecido por ley, las acciones que teóricamente podría utilizar "El Ministerio de Hacienda" contra nosotros, por ejemplo para reclamar el pago de algo ya se dice que han "prescrito", es decir, han quedado invalidadas y La Hacienda o Fisco, no podría ejercer ninguna acción legal contra nosotros.

"*Las acciones prescriben por el mero lapso de tiempo fijado por la ley*"

Así "Ejercicio más antiguo de los no prescritos", podríamos traducirlo al lenguaje común como;

"Año Fiscal más antiguo (de los que aún existan o tenga el contribuyente sin revisar) que todavía no ha sido extinguido o  "prescrito" dentro de los plazos o por el transcurso del tiempo marcado por la ley.

Por tanto Hacienda aún esta dentro de plazo temporal y puede exigir el pago u obligación a la persona de aquello que considere que aún no ha cumplido o sobre lo que aún cree tener derecho en reclamar del contribuyente" .

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por las explicaciones de ustedes! Ahora entiendo el significado de "los no prescritos" en su totalidad .

Answer (score 0):

Se refiere al IRPF impuesto sobre la renta de las personas físicas, el texto dice que los tribunales están anulando las sanciones por la entrega fuera de plazo de la declaración de bienes en el extranjero e incluso aumentando su patrimonio.

> Muchos contribuyentes no presentaron el modelo en su día por desconocimiento. Y no lo han hecho posteriormente, por las desproporcionadas sanciones previstas en la normativa para la presentación del modelo fuera de plazo. Por ello, es lógico preguntarse si las sanciones por no presentar el modelo 720 **prescriben** en algún momento.

> Una segunda “sanción”, consistente en la imputación de un incremento de patrimonio en la base liquidable del **ejercicio más antiguo de los no prescritos, por el valor de los bienes y derechos respecto de los que se hubiera incumplido la obligación de presentar el modelo 720**.

> Además, y aquí la cosa empieza a ponerse seria, Hacienda puede imputar al contribuyente, un incremento de patrimonio no justificado en el **IRPF más antiguo de los no prescrito**, por el valor de los bienes y derechos no declarados.

> Se entiende que son obligados a presentar la declaración informativa **modelo 720,** entre otros, las personas físicas residentes en territorio español, entendiéndose comprendidos a estos efectos la totalidad de contribuyentes que han de tributar en el IRPF por la integridad de su renta.

> Al establecer que el incumplimiento de la obligación informativa respecto de cuentas bancarias nuevas en el extranjero o la presentación extemporánea del modelo 720 conllevan la calificación de dichos activos como **ganancias patrimoniales no justificadas**, con independencia de la fecha de adquisición de los correspondientes activos, **sin posibilidad de ampararse en la prescripción**.

> **incremento de patrimonio**
> Fin. Variación positiva en el valor del patrimonio del contribuyente puesta de manifiesto como consecuencia de una alteración en la composición del mismo.
> Constituye el hecho imponible de varios impuestos, como el impuesto de sucesiones y donaciones, el impuesto sobre el incremento del valor de los terrenos de naturaleza urbana y con la denominación de ganancia del patrimonio en los impuestos sobre la renta. LISD, art. 3; TRLRHL, art. 104.1; LIRPF, art. 33.1. Debe distinguirse de la simple plusvalía contable.
> ganancia y pérdida de patrimonio.

[Aquí](https://www.bbva.com/es/irpf-para-dummies-de-que-hablamos-cuando-hablamos-del-impuesto-sobre-la-renta-de-personas-fisicas/amp/) y [acá](https://credexia.com/blog/como-saber-si-ha-prescrito-una-deuda-hacienda/) está explicado y [esto](https://www.lainformacion.com/economia-negocios-y-finanzas/hacienda-aplica-prescripcion-estandar-modelo-720/2859600/)

> La prescripción (extintiva o liberatoria) se produce por la inacción del acreedor por el **plazo establecido** por cada legislación conforme la naturaleza de la obligación de que se trate y tiene como efecto privar al acreedor del derecho de exigir judicialmente al deudor el cumplimiento de la obligación.