# La prescripción ... permitiendo la extinción de la acción, "mas no del derecho"

Tags: significado

Entiendo perfectamente que la prescripción permite "[la extinción de la acción](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/41218/ejercicio-m%C3%A1s-antiguo-de-los-no-prescritos?noredirect=1#comment73110_41218)" (¡muchísimas por la ayuda!) ¿pero por qué luego dice que "mas no del derecho" en el siguiente párrafo? Creo que "mas" significa "excepto", sin embargo no sé a qué se refiere "derecho" en este contexto. Y por último (perdonen ...), quisiera confirmar si "consolidar" significa "reunir" en este caso. ¡Muchas gracias!

"[La prescripció es un instituto jurídico por el cual el transcurso del tiempo produce el efecto de consolidar las situaciones de hecho, permitiendo la extinción de la acción, mas no del derecho.](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prescripci%C3%B3n_(derecho))"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**La prescripción es un instituto jurídico por el cual el transcurso del tiempo produce el efecto de consolidar las situaciones de hecho, permitiendo la extinción de la acción, mas no del derecho.**"

**Consolidar**, consolidación, en términos jurídicos significa "Reunión en un titular de facultades del dominio antes disgregadas". Aunque en este contexto "efecto de consolidar" significa que una cosa inmaterial adquiera firmeza o solidez jurídica, es decir, que las consecuencias o efectos de esa "situaciones de hecho" puedan dar lugar a la modificación, creación, transmisión o "extinción" de un derecho.

"**más no del derecho**" (aunque no del derecho). Se refiere al derecho que tiene el ámbito judicial de exigir a cualquier persona, si a así lo cree, de hacer cumplir aquello que estima. En este caso, puede que la acción haya prescrito, es decir haya trascurrido el tiempo establecido de obligar a su cumplimiento por parte de la Administración, pero eso no impide que la propia Administración de Justicia tenga el derecho de hacer una reclamación, en estos casos la persona afectada tendrá que demostrar que la prescripción verdaderamente ha prescrito, y por tanto, el supuesto derecho de la Administración de Justicia esta fuera del plazo establecido en la propia ley y como consecuencia su exigencia ya no es válida. Así por una parte, se extingue por ley la acción de actuar que tuviere la Administración, pero no su derecho de exigirlo, aunque ya no tenga razón, y de esta manera en replica lo especifique la persona afectada por esa exigencia.

"**La prescripción es un instituto jurídico por el cual el transcurso del tiempo produce el efecto de consolidar las situaciones de hecho, permitiendo la extinción de la acción, mas no del derecho.**"

**Traducción a grosso modo sin utilizar lenguaje jurídico;**

- "El "*vencimiento del plazo*" es un instituto del marco legal del Estado, por el cual el transcurso del tiempo produce el efecto de "hacer firmes" las situaciones "que se puedan derivar por ese mismo paso del tiempo", permitiendo de esta manera que el vencimiento del plazo de la acción para exigir por parte de la Administración correspondiente no tenga validez, aunque, esto no invalida el derecho que tiene la Administración de exigir a la persona aquello que considere".

La prescripción se produce cuando se acaba o agota el tiempo para hacer valer ese derecho de exigir o reclamar por parte de la Administración, por ejemplo un pago del contribuyente, que suele ser, en el caso de impuestos, de cuatro años a partir de finalizar el plazo del pago voluntario.

Para que se produzca la extinción de ese "derecho" de prescripción, por ejemplo en el caso de los impuestos es necesario que;

- Que pase el plazo establecido en la ley.
- Una vez pasado el plazo, si la Administración le reclama su derecho a que se le pague,  la persona entonces puede alegar que el plazo ha vencido.
- Que durante el plazo del periodo de extinción, la persona o titular de ese derecho no realice ninguna reclamación durante ese tiempo, ya que por ejemplo, en el caso de que la Administración de Hacienda revise nuestra declaración de la Renta antes de los cuatro años, el plazo comienza en ese momento.
- Ya que no todos los derechos prescriben, es necesario saber si existen plazos o no para la extinción de un derecho. (Por ejemplo, en otros ámbitos no prescriben nunca, "*la división de la herencia entre coherederos, división de la cosa común entre comuneros, de deslinde entre propiedades contiguas, elevar a escritura pública un documento privado...*")

Comment: !Muchísimas gracias por sus detalladas explicaciones y perdonen por no haber podido agradecerles antes!

Comment: ¡ Gracias a ti !

Answer (score 0):

'Mas no' es 'pero no'.

[La palabra mas solo se escribe sin tilde cuando es una conjunción adversativa que podría sustituirse por pero (o más raramente por sino): «Mejoró mucho, mas sigue débil» o «No sentía tristeza, mas desesperación».](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/mas-tilde-acento/)